# A Wrapping Re-sizable Horizontal List, HTML

Tags: html, css, resize, html-lists, horizontallist

[image]

I'm trying to make a re-sizable horizontal list in HTML, with some fairly specific behavior. However, I'm not sure on the best way to go about implementing it.

I have a list of fixed width items (divs, red) that I want to fill all of the allotted horizontal space with; spreading out evenly to fill the gaps. However on narrower screens that aren't able to fit all of the items in a horizontal row, I'd like another row to form containing the remaining items. This would be similar behavior to a word wrap, but the items would spread out evenly horizontally, if space permits.

It seems like there's probably a simple solution to this, but the problem is a bit too complicated to Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll struggle with that centering of the items pushing off the lines, but for the rest of it, you can do something like this:

```
#main
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}

.redDiv {
    width: 16%
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 2%;
    float: left;
```

}

Given this HTML structure:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
</div>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QwQSd/1

Comment: That's very similar to the behavior I'm looking for. However, I'd like the items to spread out evenly, when there is excess space. Also, bonus points for using the same color scheme as my image in your example.

Comment: Not quite, I edited my image to make it a bit more descriptive (see #0).

Comment: @RectangleTangle That new first image looks almost impossible to achieve without hacking the HTML to pieces/maybe using jQuery.

Comment: Here's my attempt using `inline-block` instead of `float` (so that the divs centre align correctly) - it achieves 1, 2, 3 and 4: http://jsfiddle.net/c3cE6/ - I agree with @mattytommo - image 0 can probably only be achieved via Javascript or some overly complex nested HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks Alistair! That's close enough behavior that it will suffice.